# Airflow - how to send task logs to elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, airflow

How should I configure or send task logs from airflow 1.9 to Elastic search? 
I found the config templates in the current git repository but not sure if that can be done in v 1.9

Comment: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/airflow/config_templates

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you are asking if it is possible to simply configure Airflow to send its logs directly to Elastic.

**Reference**

This is - at least for v.1.9.0 - no trivial configuration issue. Even though it says in the configuration file that you can write data to Elastic I couldn't find

1) a way to set up a proper ElasticSearch connection

2) any code in the Airflow repository using those settings to push logs to a web interface or to ElasticSearch

It seems to me this will be a new feature in the future, for reference see this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1454

**Conclusion**

So the current standard way to do this would be to log the Airflow logs to a specific folder, commonly set like this in `airflow.cfg`:

```
base_log_folder = {AIRFLOW_HOME}/logs
```

Then use a typical setup with e.g. FileBeat to send those logs, depending on your setup, directly into Elastic or into Logstash.

Comment: sure that is what I am planning to use Use a fluent D forwarder to forward the logs into Kafka from there into ElasticSearch

Comment: So how do you setup to send the logs (from files) to Elastic?